# Git - what is causing "warning: Negative patterns are ignored in git attributes"

Tags: git, gitolite

When pushing on my server the `post-receive` hook runs a `git clone` command.

The command returns the following warning and I don't know what it means or how to resolve it. 
Googling the error gave only results concerning gitattributes and I haven't configured any attributes. My .gitignore file also has no exclamation marks or negative values inside.

```
remote: Cloning into '/var/www/html/gitrep'...        
remote: warning: Negative patterns are ignored in git attributes
remote: Use '\!' for literal leading exclamation.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was solved by searching for every `.gitattributes`-file in the git repository.

One of these Files had a row starting with an exclamation mark which wasn't commented out that was causing this warning.

Answer (score 0):

> In my particular case, my top level directory only had a few choices,
>   so, since I know that I wanted to exclude, effectively, all files
>   under a, and I only wanted the expansion to occur on all files under
>   other_dir, then I changed the pattern to be:

```
other_dir/**/*.awk      ident
*.c                     ident
```

*I found this link it might help you -*

http://www.kehe.tech/questions/3254938/how-to-exclude-files-from-git-id-expansion